# Angular Directive not working when following examples

Tags: angularjs

I have been watching the following video on YouTube http://youtu.be/QwaVgz-GSXY?t=2m33s as well as others as I'm trying to learn Angular and reading other posts etc, but I just cannot seem to get the code below to work, I have viewed the response in Google developer tools, but there is no errors.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/AngularJs/myApp.js"></script>

/* use strict */
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template:'<h2>Does this work</h2>'
    }
});


<div id="test" ng-app="MyApp">
            <test></test>
        </div>
```

Comment: put the code inside the `script` tag

Comment: code is in javascript file

Comment: Try in another browser or in incognito mode. It could some caching getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please see working demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h2>Does this work</h2>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  
    <test></test>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sylwester, thanks for reply,it does work if you put ng-app="MyApp" in body, but I'm trying to add it to the div as in the video, but cannot get it to work

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson please see updated answear. Ng-app don't have to be added to body tag, but it must be placed above your directive in dom hierarchy. Make sure as well that angularjs and your script are loaded.

Comment: Hi @sylwester still does not work, no errors in Google developer. I'm missing something.

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson please create http://jsbin.com/ or http://plnkr.co/ with your code otherwise is very difficult to advice

Comment: Hi @sylwester created another test, after following this video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directives-talking-to-controllers but still no errors and does not work, ceated jsbin account and code is here: http://jsbin.com/pivutacena/1/edit

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson you've missed reference to angularjs please see here http://jsbin.com/vereqaveko/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi @sylwester that was typo by me, reference is in header on page, so it works on jsbin but not my page, there must be something on the page that is preventing it from working